# Undefined class constant 'FILTER_POS_FOOTER'

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When using  gridview tried to add property filterPosition

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterPosition'=>self::FILTER_POS_FOOTER,
   ..........
 ?>
```

But it shows as **Undefined class constant 'FILTER_POS_FOOTER'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is used to access the current class itself. In here, you're using view file which usually does not contain any classes.

Defined constant from class (`GridView` in this case) can be used by writing class's name and then it's constant. In here:

```
'filterPosition' => GridView::FILTER_POS_FOOTER,
```